# USING EFS with IIS and PHP encrypt uploaded documents

Tags: php, iis, upload, download, encrypting-file-system

My php website allows authorised users share documents by uploading and downloading documents to a document library.

I want to store the files encrypted on the server, and I am trying to use EFS, instead of explicitly encrypting/decrypting in php code on upload/download.

Server is windows server 2003/IIS

I have created a new user  on my server, logged on as this user, then encrypted the folder containing the documents using EFS.

I now want to IIS to run my web application as  so it can view the encrypted documents.  However I am having trouble with this, as  doesn't have all the permissions it needs, for example to write session files.

The other approac I have tried is to keep my website running under IUSR_Machine_Name built in user, and getting php to present user credentials when it wants to open a file for streaming, however, I'm stuck with this too.

Looking for advice on:

1. Is EFS the right approach?
2. What permissions would 
   need for IIS to use it to run my web
   application?
3. Is there any way in php to expicitly
   present user credentials at the
   point where php function *fopen* accesses my EFS 
   encrypted files?